# iPhone: How to work on this (Tab bar controller and navigation controller)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

hi i am working on  Tweet app- 1) it have Main View Controller and four sub view Controller(ie Profile view, Tweet view, setting view, help view)

2) on Main View Controller- Four UIButtons are  Profile UIButton , Tweet UIButton, Setting UIButton and Help UIButton

3)on Button action it moves to respective view (i.e on Main View Controller, clicking Profile UIButton, action Moves to Profile view Controller like this for all view respectivly)

for me i want One TabBarController, only on Profile view(NOT ON OTHER VIEW )

on Tweet View Controller with one Custom Table View (with out Tab Bar Controller)

On all view,Move Back to Main View Controller (view) one navigation Item (Note;- not on Main View Controller)

can i do this, i work on this NOT getting output

How i have to work on this, to work the app

Thank you
nanda

Answer (score 1):

You can make this by using tabBar application in xcode's new project then you need to make tabs and for each tab use navigation controller and set mainwindow's load sreen by setting nib name in main window and controller file(in inspector for main window). you need to implement like following-

[image]

Comment: thank you, ishu Gupta,1) can we load tabBarController on second view but not on the First view(main view),2) if con't we work on Universal app like this

Comment: we can hide the tabbar.But what you want that is tricky task.And we also can make app which supports iphone and ipad for this you need to code for both in same app.